# Where is de Data Viewer from ChronoForms v5?

Tags: joomla2.5, chronoforms

I'm using ChronoForms v5 in Joomla! 2.5.

After creating the form (the server-side logic is not done yet) I want to see the Data Viewer for the form. So I entered the DB Viewer section to add fields and labels to be displayed:

[image]

But: Where is, actually, the Data Viewer* feature? Official docs are not clear about that.

(* notice the label immediately below the textarea)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the data you have to come back to the "Forms Manager".
In the column "Connected Tables" you can choose the table you want to see.

*Note:* Using Chronoform you can see the data only in the backend (administration). If you need to see the data from the front end you can use ChronoConnectivity.